# class in python with method acting on self. inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I guess it would be easy for me to explain the question with an examply
Suppose I want to write my own vector class.
And in that class let say i want to define a method to add 2 vectors 
something like:

```
class vector:
.....
def add(self,other):
    ----some code
```

so basically what this will do is.. if a vector is vec
then

```
vec.add(othervec)
```

will do the addition..
but how do i do this..
its like inherting your own class..datatype
?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add two classes, I'd look at the `__add__` function, which allows you to do normal addition (and not call `.add()`):

```
a + b
```

As for your question, I'm not exactly sure about what you're asking. I wrote my `Vector()` class like this:

```
class Vector:
  def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z

  def __add__(self, other):
    return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z)
```

Comment: Cool.. This works :) Or I think this will also work.. if we declare class as class Vector(object): ?? right??

Comment: Sure. As long as the object has `.x`, `.y`, and `.z` properties, this should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you should use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), i.e. not worry about the type at all:

```
class Vector(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  def add(self, othervec):
    return Vector(self.x + othervec.x, self.y + othervec.y)
```

If you want, you can make `add` *modify* the Vector object instead of returning a new one. However, that makes your class mutable and therefore harder to deal with:

```
  def add_mutable(self, othervec):
    self.x += othervec.x
    self.y += othervec.y
```

Answer (score 1):

sure, you can do exactly as you said, suppose you are wanting to add / change functionality of list

```
class Vector(list):

    def add(self, v):
        list.extend(self, v)
```

and you can use it like this:

```
> v = Vector([1,2,3])
> v.add([4,5,6])
> print v
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```